# how to handle apostrophe in a string in sqlite in uwp

Tags: .net, sqlite, uwp, where-clause, apostrophe

I am working on uwp app. Here I am facing a problem that is when I am comparing a string which contains apostrophe. The sqlite query is giving exception.

How can handle apostrophe in sqlite in uwp. 
At **Men's Wear** string in below code am getting exception.

```
 SELECT SKU_MASTER.sku_Id, SKU_MASTER.short_description,SKU_MASTER.product_Id,PRODUCT_MASTER.product_ID,PRODUCT_MASTER.sub_category
        FROM SKU_MASTER INNER JOIN PRODUCT_MASTER ON SKU_MASTER.product_Id == PRODUCT_MASTER.product_ID and  PRODUCT_MASTER.category='APPAREL' and PRODUCT_MASTER.sub_category='MEN'S WEAR'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of SQLiteParameter in your application that way any text won't be interpreted as part of the SQL statement itself, this in fact demonstrates an SQL injection scenario as that apostrophe can be used to escape from the normal instruction and add something else. I think you replace the values with '?' instead then for the Command you add the relevant parameters and their values.

Comment: con.Query<Sku_Master>($"select sm.sku_Id ,sm.short_description from Sku_Master as sm , Product_Master as pm  where sm.product_Id == pm.product_ID and pm.sub_category='?' and pm.category='{objcategory.category}'", strArray[0]);                                          not giving the result.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with SQLite has have only doe this with SQL Server, is something I wish I knew more about to help more

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SKU_MASTER.sku_Id, SKU_MASTER.short_description FROM SKU_MASTER INNER JOIN PRODUCT_MASTER ON SKU_MASTER.product_Id = PRODUCT_MASTER.product_ID and PRODUCT_MASTER.category = '{objcategory.category}' and PRODUCT_MASTER.sub_category = **?** ", strArray[0]

It will give the result.
Here I am passing string as parameter.
taken References from https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net